# `useQuery` does not have access to the data in the first place

Tags: javascript

```js
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import {GET_POST_DETAIL} from "../utils/queryData"

const BlogDetail = () => {
  let {id} = useParams()
  id = parseInt(id)
  const {data} =  useQuery(GET_POST_DETAIL, {
    variables: { id }
  })
  const post = data?.post[0]
  console.log(post)
  return ( 
    <main>
      <h1>{post?.title}</h1>
      <section>{post?.date}</section>
      <p>{post?.content}</p>
    </main>
   );
}
 
export default BlogDetail;
```

I can't get the 'data' I want the first time, as in the image below. Instead, the component is re-mounted, which doesn't seem normal,

[`console.log(post)`  in code print picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa6WB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the loading and error states from the useQuery hook to handle the different states of the query

```js
const BlogDetail = () => {
    let { id } = useParams();
    id = parseInt(id);
    const { loading, data } = useQuery(GET_POST_DETAIL, {
        variables: { id },
    });

    if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;

    const post = data?.post[0];

    return (
        <main>
            <h1>{post?.title}</h1>
            <section>{post?.date}</section>
            <p>{post?.content}</p>
        </main>
    );
};
```

Comment: I want to ask if the above situation is normal?

Comment: Yes, it is normal.

Comment: you see this link [apollo client offical example](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-a-query) ,It can fetch the data directly, which we can't

Comment: There will be a delay for fetching the data, during this delay the loading state will be true, in the examples you can see loading and error states handled